# SFSY-FORMPAGES shows * before page 10

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

I'm implementing my SAP smartform and I'm showing current and total pages.
When I call the variable:

```
SFSY-FORMPAGES
```

in pages 1-9, it becomes *. After page 10, it has the correct value. Why??

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the General Attributes tab of the page?  Is the Mode correct for your use?

There are format conditions which can be used in your SAP Smart Forms documents. Due to FORMPAGES being 4 characters long, the formatting shown below will remove the asterisk for formpages & jobpages.
&sfsy-formpages(4CZ)&
&sfsy-jobpages(4CZ)&

[System Fields](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/1c/f40c67ddf311d3b574006094192fe3/content.htm)
[Creating Pages](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/70/e17a2cdec511d3b575006094192fe3/content.htm)